How to start a devcontainer from an image with a non-existent user and set the UID automatically
I want to create a devcontainer from an existing image with the same username and UID as the host user.
I had no problem starting the devcontainer from an existing image.
I also was able to add the user by running useradd as a postCreateCommand and, additionally, setting the remoteUser field. I get the name of the user by using ${localEnv:USER}.
But I don't know how to set the UID in the container to the same value as the host UID. I could add it to the useradd command, but ${localEnv:UID} doesn't work, because the UID is not globally exported in bash and when I try to create the container with CLion, the variables' name is empty. There would be the updateRemoteUserUID field according to the devcontainer reference, but it doesn't do anything. Maybe because the user doesn't exist yet upon creation.
Is there a way to automatically set the UID of a newly created user to the same value as the hosts UID?
